# IIS 8 .net 2.0 aspx pages run when accessed as localhost, but other domain bindings results in runtime error

Tags: .net, iis-8, asp.net

I have IIS 8 running with .net 2,3,3.5,4 all installed. I have a .net 2.0 website that will only execute when access in a browser using a localhost(127.0.0.1) binding. If i try to access the site with it's domain i am returned a Runtime Error page.

Seems to be a permissions issue? the aspx pages execute just fine when accessed http://localhost/default.aspx (example).

Comment: So .net 4 websites work fine remotely?, static files in the .net 2 site work fine remotely? What is the runtime error you are getting?

Comment: yes and yes. I can't see the runtime error even with custom errors set to off and compilation debug set to true. I get the below: Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: Anything in the application event log?